# flutter pubspec.yaml showing error in run time

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I'm trying to run this flutter code, I do not know what is wrong
I already update pubspect.yaml

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NameCapitalize extends StatelessWidget {
  const NameCapitalize({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        
        child: Stack(
          //Widget i make like a table and split the screen into rows and columns
          children: [
            Column(
              children:[
                Text("Hi Their!")
                svgPicture.asset('assets/icons/chat.svg')
              ],
            ),
            //Widget i move by using left and right top and bottom commands
        Positioned(
          child: Image.asset("assets/images/main_top.png"),
          //child hear is a picture use to decorate app page
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Image.asset("assets/images/main_bottom.png"),
          //child hear is a picture use to decorate app page
        ),
       ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}

----- end of code ----
```

here the error :

```
Error on line 64, column 6: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   ╷
64 │      - assets/images/
   │      ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at /Users/adelalshehri/StudioProjects/Flutter_Final_Project_Level1/pubspec.yaml
```

Comment: paste the pubspec.yaml file, the error is there not the dart file.

see if 'assets' is there in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Hey can you show your pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have proper spacing before asset image, it will be like

```dart
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/file.xml
    - assets/alice.png
    - assets/Sukuna.jpg
```

The main `assets:` have two space before it,maked as yellow

and inside it images contains 4 spaces, marked as red color

[image]